# libde265.pc is not created by cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm building the libde265 library like this:

```
cd libde265
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/src/build ..
make
make install
```

Everything builds fine, however libde265.pc is not created anywhere on the filesystem. I see it [here](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/blob/8aed7472df0af25b811828fa14f2f169dc34d35a/configure.ac#L389), but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, since I don't understand why it works, but I struggled with this issue all morning and found the following solution.

Although the documentation says to cmake in a directory ./build, I found that if I just cmake, make and install from the base directory it works and creates libde265.pc in the appropriate place.